# `git branch --contains` does not show branch that originated commit

Tags: git, commit, git-branch

I wanted to test git branch --contains, so I found a commit from a branch that I had not checked out before, `older-branch`.

On a different, more current branch (lets call it newer-branch), I did `git fetch` to make sure I was up-to-date with upstream. Then I did, `git branch older-branch --contains COMMITHASH`

But this did not return older-branch.

Furthermore, when I did `git branch --contains COMMITHASH` it showed newer-branch however it did not show older-branch in the list.

Confused, I did `git checkout older-branch` and then `git branch contains older-branch --contains COMMITHASH` and it returned older-branch! I then did `git branch --contains COMMITHASH` and it showed older-branch along with the newer branch that I originally tested out these git commands on!

I then switched back to the newer-branch. This time, when I did `git branch older-branch --contains COMMITHASH` it showed older-branch! Why is this?

Comment: It looks like some of the commands you're specifying are not standard Git commands.  For example, `git contains` and `git older-branch` are not built-in Git commands.  You may want to edit your post and make it reflect a standard set of commands.

Comment: @bk2204 you're right! i corrected my post. thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still full of odd-looking constructs like:

> ```
> git branch contains older-branch --contains COMMITHASH
> ```

but I *think* I understand what you are doing and asking.  (Note that a more-focused question could get a more-focused answer.)  I *think* the answer you want is `git branch -r --contains`.  But in case it isn't....

The basic mistake you are making here is thinking that branch names actually mean anything to Git. :-)  More specifically, you're assuming that *your* branch names get updated automatically when some *other* Git repository updates *their* branch names.

This is not the case.

When you run `git fetch`, you have your Git call up some other Git repository somewhere.  Typically you will have exactly one other Git repository, which you will call `origin`.  You can, however, list multiple different other Git repositories.  You just have to make up a unique name for each one.

Now, suppose the Git repository over at `origin`, which resides at some URL *`url`*, has three branch names: `master`, `develop`, and `feature`.  When you run:

```
$ git clone <url>
```

you get a Git repository of your own.  *Your* Git repository now knows of another Git repository—the one at *`url`*—and has saved that URL under the name `origin`:

```
$ git remote
origin
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ...
  ... lots more stuff ...
```

The *second* `git remote` command here actually called up that other Git to get information from it.  *Most* commands, by far, in Git *don't* call up any other Git: they only look inside *your* Git repository.

At this point, *your* Git repository has only *one* branch name, almost certainly `master`.<sup>1</sup>  If you run `git branch` to list your branch names, you'll see that one branch.

Does this mean that branches `develop` and `feature` don't exist in your repository?  The answer to that is both no and yes.  The problem is determining what you mean by *branch*.  See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

The *commits* you might care about here do exist.  And in fact, some *names* you might want to use exist too!  The names that *don't* exist are the *branch names* `develop` and `feature`.

If you run:

```
git branch --contains <hash-id>
```

you will *definitely not* see the name `develop`, because *you* do not have the name `develop`.

> I did `git fetch` to make sure I was up-to-date with upstream.

That is the—or *a*, at least—right thing to do.

> ... Confused, I did `git checkout older-branch` and then [`git branch --contains` worked for me]

This is because `git checkout` will sometimes *create* a new *branch name*.

**The key here is once again the ambiguous meaning of the word *branch*.**  If you mean *branch name*, you must have the *name*.  But if you mean something else, well....

Besides *branch names*, your own Git repository has what I now call *remote-tracking names*.  Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names*—but they are not *branch* names at all.

When you run `git fetch origin`, or a `git fetch` that uses `origin`, your Git calls up the Git over at `origin`.  They have a conversation, and your Git will obtain any commits they have, that you don't, that your Git would like to take.  Your Git will then update your *remote-tracking names*.

Your remote-tracking names in this case would be `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and `origin/feature`.  Your Git creates one for every *branch name* your Git sees in their Git.

These remote-tracking names remember, for you / your Git, that *their* Git had *branch* names, and what commit hash IDs those branch names held.  A `git fetch` will update them.  (If they've deleted some branch names, you can use `git fetch --prune` to have your Git delete your corresponding remote-tracking names.  Without a pruning option, your Git will hang on to extra remote-tracking names.  This prune mode probably *should* be the default, but for historical reasons, isn't.)

*Your* branch names are just that: *yours*.  Just because Fred has added, deleted, and changed some of *his* branch names, that doesn't mean your Git will change *yours*.  If you connect your Git to a remote named `fred`, your Git will update your `fred/*` names automatically, because your Fred-tracking names, while yours, are meant for remembering Fred's.  The same goes with your `origin`-tracking names.

When you did `git checkout older-branch`, though, your `git checkout` command looked through *your* branch names.  The name `older-branch` wasn't in there.  Rather than just giving up right away and saying: *you don't have that branch*, your Git went on to look at all of your *remote-tracking* names.

If you have one remote-tracking name that looks enough like the branch name you asked for, your Git now *creates* a branch name of your own, corresponding to that remote-tracking name.  So if you have `origin/older-branch`, well, now you *do* have `older-branch`.  The commit identified by `older-branch` will be the *same* commit hash ID that `origin/older-branch` identifies right now

Now that you do have a branch name, it's up to you to maintain it.  It's probably wiser to delete it and use `origin/older-branch` directly.  The `git branch` command won't list remote-tracking names by default, but with the `-r` option, that's exactly what it *will* list.  So `git branch -r --contains` will list those remote-tracking names where the remote-tracking name's commit is a descendant of the commit hash you specify on the command line.

---

<sup>1</sup>The *other* Git gets to say which branch name you get by default, if you didn't get specific in your `git clone` command about which branch your `git clone` should create.  But unless someone sets it up otherwise, the other Git says *I recommend `master`* so that's what you usually get anyway.